# JPA cannot delete entities with a onotomany relation and a cascatype all

Tags: java, jpa, entity, one-to-many, entitymanager

I am trying to delete an entity but when I use the entity manager i do not have errors but te data is still in the database, I am using cascade all, independently of this, I am deleting its parent reference as

```
Parent parent = child.getParent();
parent.getChildren().remove(child);
entityManager.remove(child);
entityManager.merge(parent);
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Check that you are in a transaction, and that entityManager.flush() pushes the statements to the database.  If you are in a transaction, nothing occurs until it commits (or you call flush), while if you are not in a transaction, nothing will ever occur - though flush should give you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This can have several reasons:

You are not removing the parent reference from the child - `child.setParent(null);`
This is important since the parent `id` is probably stored inside the child table.

The removal is not committed yet when you are calling `merge`. This should not be an issue, but if the first idea does not help I would try and put the deletion and the merge in separate transactions.

I assume that you are using `CascadeType.ALL` on the parent only.

Answer (score 0):

Edit according to Chris comment because it was indeed not clear at all.

1st, you have to understand than an entity instance can have many states. http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_em_lifecycle.html

Merge is here to attach an entity to the current entityManager. Once it's managed, all modification you will make on the entity will be persisted in database when the EntityManager is flushed. This happen normally at the end of the current transaction (or when you call flush manually or when the entityManager estimates that it's necessary).

If your entities have been retrieved from the DB inside the current transaction, you don't need to call merge as they already are managed.

Assuming this

You just need to call

```
entityManager.remove(child);
```

Or

```
parent.getChildren().remove(child);
```

if you've configured orphan removal on the relationship (in parent).

This will so be automatically flused to the database **when the current transaction will be flushed and NOT at the method call**.

Otherwise you can force flushing by using `entityManager.flush()`but it's a bad practice. Anyway you won't see the change in the database until the transaction is commited / closed.

If you want to remove a child using `entityManager.remove(child)` you must ensure to apply associated modification on parent entity (using `parent.getChildren().remove(child)` and not `entityManager.refresh(parent)`) if your parent instance is currently managed (means it actually exists an instance of your parent in memory, because you've retrieved it or because you've called child.getParent() or because it was eagerly loaded when you retrieved the child.)

Comment: You should maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships, or the entity is out of synch with what is in the database.  It also runs the risk of inadvertently resurrecting entities if a relationship to the removed entity is marked cascade persist and isn't cleaned up.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for rectification